# Should synthetic cloth materials be avoided?

Tags: clothes, synthetic-fabric, waterproof-repellent

There are many articles ([example](https://www.cancerdefeated.com/newsletters/The-Clothes-that-Kill-You-Slowly-but-Surely.html%3E)) that warm about latest research on modern synthetic cloth materials such as Acryl, Nylon considered toxic and can lead to cancer.

> The Chemicals You Wear Every Day… With a "mere" 8,000 chemicals used
> in clothing manufacture, it's a sure bet you're wearing many as you
> read this. Let's highlight some of the worst. These kinds of fabric
> finishes "scream" chemicals...
>
> 1. Easy Care — Wrinkle free, shrinkage free garments release formaldehyde.
> 2. Water Repellent — Fluoropolymers (as in Teflon) are used to repel oil and water
> 3. Flame Retardants
> 4. Bacterial and fungicidal chemicals — Triclosan and nano-particles are used for this. Formaldehyde is linked to a 30% increase in lung
>    cancer, plus skin/lung irritation and contact dermatitis. It is found
>    in fabrics claiming to be:
> 5. Anti-cling, anti-static, anti-shrink
> 6. Waterproof
> 7. Perspiration-proof
> 8. Moth-proof and mildew resistant Chorine resistant

Another mentioning is in book **Encyclopedia of Cancer and Society** page 4. (available preview at Google Books)

> One of these thousands of chemicals used to produce synthetic fabric
> is formaldehyde – and this single chemical has been linked to a 30%
> increase in lung cancer.
>
> Most governments regulate formaldehyde levels in the toxic clothing we
> all wear; however, the United States government does not.

source: undergroundhealthreporter.com/toxic-clothing-synthetic-fibers-hazard-to-health/

Is it true? What is medical community's opinion?

I noted that most cheap clothing such as fall/winter beanies made from acryl. Even the ones from widely known manufacturer Thinsulate ([★★★★★4.6/5 stars](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Unisex-Womens-Thinsulate-Winter-Thermal/dp/B00FG0E05A/ref=cts_ap_2_vtp?_encoding=UTF8&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_p=1069525627&pf_rd_r=DX1P9EJQBDNA5WW3YHMG&pd_rd_wg=gfsoX&pf_rd_s=desktop-detail-softlines&pf_rd_t=40701&pd_rd_i=B00FG0E05A&pd_rd_w=0XEJZ&pf_rd_i=desktop-detail-softlines&pd_rd_r=DX1P9EJQBDNA5WW3YHMG)). Does it mean the manufacturer opted for cheaper and more toxic materials in order to cut costs and offer competitive market prices? Some articles state that US does not  regulate the amount of formaldehyde. True? What about EU?

Comment: Clothing contains formaldehyde and formaldehyde causes cancer. Therefore, clothing causes cancer? https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/appeal-to-nature https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/false-cause

Comment: When you research a topic, always aim to challenge your own assumptions and findings and don't just accept one side of the argument:
https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/causes-prevention/risk/substances/formaldehyde/formaldehyde-fact-sheet

Comment: Also, cut down the questions to only 1, (2 at most).